# Утечка памяти при отправке асинхронных HTTP запросов на сервер

Tags: python

```
from restclient import GET

items = [
            ["https://e.mail.ru/"]]

def purchase(item):
   GET(item async = True, resp = False)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
            for num in items:
                purchase(num)
            time.sleep(0.3)
```

Данный код в бесконечном цикле, в идеале, должен посылать на сервер асинхронный запрос. Ответ сервера мне не нужен. В реальности происходит так, как и планировалось, но происходит утечка памяти, которая подвешивает компьютер.

Единственное, что происходит на ум, - это то, что функция `GET` создает бесконечное количество потоков, которые не освобождаются после отработки запроса. Но могу ошибаться.

Как избежать утечки памяти и сохранить возможность бесконечно слать асинхронные запросы на сервер?

Comment: А зачем асинхронные?

Comment: в данном контексте мне важна скорость отправки запросов, то есть в идеале мне надо посылать около 200-т запросов за 0.3-0.4 секунды постоянно. Отсюда решение использовать асинхронные запросы, так как время обработки одного  обычного запроса получается около 0.4 секунды, соответственно  20 + запросов стоят непозволительно много времени. Буду рад альтернативным предложениям по решению этого вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться профилировщиком памяти. Тогда вы легко сможете определить, где происходит утечка.

Comment: 700k http-запросов в секунду — это по моему за пределами возможностей любого современного компьютера, что-то здесь определённо не так, или в комментарии, или в задаче -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать заменить: `thread.start_new_thread(func, args)` на `threading.Thread(target=func, args=args).start()`, но в лучшем случае это только откладывает проблему.

Каждый `GET(async=True)` создаёт новый поток, если запрос занимает больше чем `0.3/len(items)` секунд, то новый цикл начинается до того как потоки с предущей итерации закончились -- это только может увеличить время на запрос, что усугубляет проблему и кол-во потоков растёт с каждой итерацией. В районе от 100 до 10000 потоков создаётся эффект "подвешивания компьютера".

Чтобы ограничить число потоков, можно использовать пул потоков:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import deque
from itertools import cycle
from multiprocessing import ThreadPool

def make_request(item):
    pass # make blocking http request here

deque(ThreadPool(20).imap_unordered(make_request, cycle(items), chunksize=100),
      maxlen=0)
```

[Автор `restclient` рекомендует `requests` использовать](https://github.com/thraxil/restclient/#status-note), хотя в этом случае даже напрямую поверх `socket` или `httplib` можно писать, [пример кода](https://gist.github.com/zed/0a8860f4f9a824561b51).